# Bigcommerce free shipping based on customer group

Tags: java, php, bigcommerce

Is it possible within my bigcommerce site to define the free shipping price based on which customer group the user belongs to?

Comment: Yes it is. Provide a link to your site, and the code showing the customer group variables so that we know what the problem is.

Comment: ShipperHQ allows you to do this without code.

Comment: Thanks Alyss! We haven't made the switch to using ShipperHQ just yet but were considering it. This only helps with our decision to start using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define free shipping based on customer group without having to use code as an app exists that covers this. You can get more information on [configuring ShipperHQ here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Setting-Up-ShipperHQ/).

Alternatively, you could do this in blueprint checkout, but you'd have to rely on ajax calls to update the displayed options.

```
if ('%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%%' == X) {
 $('div:contains(Free Shipping)').show();
}
else {
 $('div:contains(Free Shipping)').hide();
}
```

My code is jquery dependent and would need tweaks to activate on an ajax call.